# How to sync when render a component?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

i have a problem when i try catch new data went i change something in my content and render it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withNamespaces } from "react-i18next";

class Untitled extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.columns = [...content]
  }
  render() {
    const columns = this.columns.map((col) => {
      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: (record) => ({
          record,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
        }),
      };
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {columns}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Untitled
```

Here, when i change some values in [...content] i want "const columns" will update this new values and render it in return(). I am sure when [...content] update a new value had update in render(). But "const columns" still keep old value.

P/s: I cannot declare this.columns like this.state { columns: [] } because i don't want change code of old dev. Exactly i want get new value this.props.t("TEST") in this.columns when it toggle language.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this.forceUpdate()` to manually trigger a re render
. You can get more explanation here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate